# Pandas sum by date indexed but exclude totals column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is being read from database records and looks like this:

```
date          added    total
2020-09-14        5        5
2020-09-15        4        9
2020-09-16        2        11
```

I need to be able to `resample` by different periods and this is what I am using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(raw_data, index='date')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# let's say I want yearly sample, then I would do
df = df.fillna(0).resample('Y').sum()
```

This almost works, but it is obviously `summing` the `total` column, which is something I don't want. I need total column to be the value in the `date` sampled in the dataframe, like this:

```
# What I need
date    added    total
2020       11       11

# What I'm getting
date    added    total
2020       11       25
```

Comment: Isn't `total` same as `added`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by resampling differently for different columns. Here you want to use `sum()` aggregator for the **added** column, but `max()` for the **total**.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[20200914, 20200915, 20200916, 20210101, 20210102], 
                   'added':[5, 4, 2, 1, 6], 
                   'total':[5, 9, 11, 1, 7]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')

df_res = df.resample('Y', on='date').agg({'added':'sum', 'total':'max'})
```

And the result is:

```
df_res
            added  total
date                    
2020-12-31     11     11
2021-12-31      7      7
```

Comment: Simply do `df.resample('Y', on='date').agg({"added": "sum", "total": "max"})` instead of resampling twice and concat.

Comment: Oh yeah, that would be better! I'll update my answer, thanks!